# Ordering result with PDO and prepared statment

Tags: php, pdo, sql-order-by, prepared-statement

This does not work:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM location ORDER BY ? ASC");
$orderValue = "location_name";
$stmt->execute([$orderValue]);
```

How can I ortder the result by location_name?

Comment: You can't generally (i.e. this isn't always true depending on things like emulate_prepares) use placeholders for identifiers (column names for example). Depending on where the identifier string comes from (location_name in this case), you can put the name directly in the query.

Comment: Thanks! The value to order by is hard coded by me. It should be safe to put it in the query then, right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine in this case.

Comment: @Jonnix it is *always* true

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'll happily take your word for it. There was just something niggling in the back of my mind about placeholders and emulation working differently.

Comment: Different people understand the term "hardcode" differently, so make sure the field name is [indeed chosen from values *explicitly* written in your *PHP* code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/order_by).